# Column cannot be null, but it is filled

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, entity, laminas

This error is happening below, but I am passing a value to the column.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tbevt_votacaostatusopcao (clvotacaostatusopcao_idintegracao, clvotacaostatusopcao_idopcao, clvotacaosta
tusopcao_nome) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "23094", "Sim"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'clvotacaostatusopcao_idintegracao' cannot be null
```

My Entity:

```
/**
     * @var VotacaoIntegracao
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Evento\Entity\VotacaoIntegracao", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="clvotacaostatus_idintegracao", referencedColumnName="clvotacaointegracao_idintegracao")
     */
    protected $integracao;

    /**
     * @var VotacaoStatusOpcao
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Evento\Entity\VotacaoStatusOpcao", mappedBy="opcao")
     */
    protected $votacaoStatusOpcao;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="clvotacaostatus_idintegracao", type="integer")
     */
    protected $idIntegracao;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="clvotacaostatus_idstatus", type="integer")
     */
    protected $idStatus;
```

My Service:

```
$this->entityManager->persist($votacaoStatus);
$votacaoStatus->setIdIntegracao($idIntegracao);
$votacaoStatus->setIdStatus($situacaoVotacao);
$this->entityManager->flush($votacaoStatus);
$this->entityManager->commit();
```

If I comment on the `protected $integracao` variable, the insert works, but I need this link. But I know the error is here.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Both `$integracao` and `idIntegracao` are mapped to the same column `clvotacaostatus_idintegracao`. This looks like a mistake, probably you are setting one field and not another and later down the line Doctrine tries to save `null` value that comes from one of the fields

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried to remove the $idIntegration mapping, but the error persists.

Comment: Have you cleared the mapping cache afterwards?

Comment: Yes, same problem.